# Reciprocal using Newton Raphson

Tags: approximation, newton-raphson

Say you want to calculate 1/R using Newton-Rapshon method. Then we let,

$$f(x) = 1/x - R$$

This means the root of the this function is at $f(1/R)$. So to find $1/R$, you can find the root of this function using Newton-Raphson method.

I got this part. Your first Newton-Raphson iteration would be:

$x_1 = x_0 + x(1-xR)$ as you know that $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=-x(1-xR)$

Now I'd like to prove that the error satisfies:

$\frac{r-r_1}{r} = (\frac{r-r_0}{r})^2$

Where $r=1/R$

How can I prove this?

I found on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division

It says that the number of correct digits doubles each time. This *should* mean that the relative error is squared each time. So relative error of $r_1$ should be the square of relative error of $r_0$... So I *should* be able to prove this statement true.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x_1 = x_0 + x_0\left(1-\frac{x_0}{r}\right)$, hence $r - x_1 = \frac{x_0^2}{r} - 2x_0 + r$, and $\frac{r - x_1}{r} = \frac{x_0^2 - 2x_0 r + r^2}{r^2}= \left(\frac{r-x_0}{r}\right)^2$.

Comment: How did you get $r-x_1 = ...$

Comment: Expand RHS, subtract $r$ from both sides, change signs.

Comment: The final result I need is $\frac{r-r_1}{r}$, not $\frac{r-x_1}{r}$. Might be hard to read but it's $r_1$ not $x_1$

Comment: What is $r_1$? I do not see it defined.

Comment: $r_i = 1/R_i$. I defined it without the subscript i

Comment: What is $R_i$? I do not see it defined in the statement of the problem.

Comment: oh sorry, $r_i = 1/x_i$. Sorry sorry! And $r=1/R$.

Comment: That cannot be. Take e.g. $R=1$ and $x_0=0.5$, Then you get $x_1=0.75$, which satisfies the relation I just proved, however with $r_i = 1/x_i$ we have r_0=2, $r_1= 4/3$, the LHS would become negative and the RHS is positive.

Comment: Another constraint on the problem is that $x_i$ is accurate in half the digits to $R$.

Comment: $x_0$ is accurate in half the digits I mean

Comment: I think $x_i=r_i$ which is what gave me the expression to be derived. It makes sense because $x_{final}=\frac1{R}$ and $r=\frac1{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of easy algebra I'll work with signed errors. Since $x_1=x_0(2-Rx_0)$, the absolute errors $\epsilon_i:=x_i-\frac{1}{R}$ satisfy $\epsilon_1=(\epsilon_0+\frac{1}{R})(1-R\epsilon_0)-\frac{1}{R}=-R\epsilon_0^2$, so the relative errors $\delta_i:=R\epsilon_i$ satisfy $\delta_1=-\delta_0^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply plug the values of $r_0$ and $r_1$:

$$\frac{r-r_1}{r} = \left(\frac{r-r_0}{r}\right)^2$$
comes from 
$$\frac{r-(r_0 + r_0(1-r_0R))}{r} = \left(\frac{r-r_0}{r}\right)^2$$

which is true because

$$\frac{r-(r_0 + r_0(1-r_0R))}{r}=\frac{r^2-2rr_0 +r_0^2}{r^2}.$$